# How to store a default array for remote config?

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to store some values in Remote Config that I want to be able to present to users as a list options in a preference screen.

I have the list pref working fine as a static list with the usual xml file values, and I have the remote config (stored as a JSON array) being able to be read fine.

My problem is how to store a default list that can be replaced by the ones read from the remote config.

I've tried storing them in a List in the activity with a getter for wherever it might work, but I can't find anything about how to read the defaults for the preference screen (either by a default in xml or by even hard coding it).

Any hints to point me in the right direction would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the default remote config values within the app in an xml file.

Create a remote_config_defaults.xml file in res/xml/remote_config_defaults.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- START xml_defaults -->
<defaultsMap>
<entry>
    <key>topics</key>
    <value>{"topics":[{"topic":"all"},{"topic":"general"},{"topic":"technology"}, 
        {"topic":"sports"},{"topic":"entertainment"},{"topic":"politics"}]}</value>
</entry>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't thinking I could put the whole JSON in as the value.

Comment: how to storeboolean